# How to filter out 2 ids in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have below code which is filtering out menu id value 8

```
oListVM = oListVM.Where(x => x.MenuID != 8).ToList();  //filter out menu id 8
```

But I wanted to filter out menu id 8 and 13 so I decided to write the code like this. Is this the right way to filter out both 8 and 13 menu id? I recently started working with c# and 
.net.

```
oListVM = oListVM.Where(x => (x.MenuID != 8 && x.MenuID!=13)).ToList();  //filter out menu id 8 and 13
```

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: use debugging and see for yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right

```
oListVM = oListVM.Where(x => (x.MenuID != 8 && x.MenuID!=13)).ToList();  //filter out menu id 8 and 13
```

is a valid way to do. In additional, say you have more than 2 ids, just use `Array` or `List`:

```
int[] filterArray = new int[6] {1,5,6,8,13,14};
oListVM = oListVM.Where(x => !filterArray.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
oListVM = oListVM
    .Where(x => x.MenuID != 8)
    .Where(x => x.MenuID != 13)
    .ToList();  //filter out menu id 8 and 13
```

Link is evaluated when it is "accessed" - by `.ToList()` you access and persist the whole iteration at once. It makes no difference for the Linq-Statement if you cram all conditions into one `Where` conditional or if you chain them.

If you decide to also block 14, 18, 22 you could also use another linq to check if any is (not) in a list of things:

```
var doNotShow = new [] {8, 13, 14, 18, 22};
oListVM = oListVM
    .Where(x => ! doNotShow.Any(d => x == d))
    .ToList();
```